# Django - создание модели внутри другой

Tags: python, django

Не могу понять, как сделать в django 3.0 создание модели внутри другой модели, примерно как в админке через inlines. Чтобы пользователь, выбирая объект, мог в нем создать договор(а), который(ые) привязан (имел связь) к данному объекту и отображался при создании в общем списке в объекте. Объект может быть только один у договора, а договоров может быть много у объекта.
И в данном случае, правильнее связь через ManyToManyField или ForeignKey.

models.py

```
# основной класс
class Object(models.Model):
    id_object = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="ID Объекта", unique=True)
    #dogovor = models.ManyToManyField('Dogovor', blank=True, related_name='object_rs')

# другие поля

# связанный класс
class Dogovor(models.Model):
    object_d = models.ForeignKey(Object, null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Объект')
    num_contract = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, verbose_name='Номер договора', db_index=True, null=False)

# другие поля
```

object_detail.html

```
{% extends "base_realestateworks.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h3 class="mb-5">Object name: "{{ object }}"</h3>
<p>

</p>
<div class="container-fluid">
            <table class="table">

                    <table class="table">
                      <tbody>
                      {% for ob in object_d %}
                        <tr>       
                          <td> {{ ob.slug }}</td>
                          <td>{{ ob.adress_object }}</td>
                          <td>{{ ob.purpose_object }}</td>
                          <td>{{ ob.object_type }}</td>
                          <td>{{ ob.data_pub }}</td>
                          <td>{{ ob.last_save_date }}</td>
                          <td>{{ ob.user}}</td>
                        </tr>
                      {% endfor %}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
            </table>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Так у Вас всё правильно написано. За исключением названия Object, которое нельзя использовать в python в общем случае. Сделайте рефакторинг.

Comment: object у него с большой буквы, думаю что это не вызовет конфликта. а вот создание одной модели из другой через inlines и настраивается.

Comment: alex - да у меня получилось, но через админку, а через шаблон не выдает. {% for ob in object_d %}

Comment: @ЕвгенийДанилюк так приведите код шаблона :)

Comment: @Михаил Алексеевич приложил. не могу понять, как получить доступ к списку договоров данного объекта.

Comment: @ЕвгенийДанилюк так Вам надо выдать объект для договора, или все договора для объекта? Или вообще нужно их редактировать?

Comment: @Михаил Алексеевич выдать все договора выбранного объекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение по отображению списка договоров у объекта следующее (помогла данная статья https://metanit.com/python/django/5.6.php):

Надо было заменить в шаблоне:

```
{% for ob in object_d %}
```

на:

```
{% for ob in object.dogovor_set.all %}
```

и обратиться через:

```
{{ ob.num_contract }}
```

Решение по  созданию модели (договор) внутри другой модели (объекта) с автоматической привязкой договора к объекту, примерно как в админке через inlines. Решение нашел в сети, исправил views.py:

```
class DogovorCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'realestateworks/dogovor_create.html'
    form_class = DogovorForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
         object_d = BaseObject.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
         form.instance.object_d = object_d
         return super(DogovorCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```